# With Django, why do I get 404 errors on static resources during login?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am taking over a project that was developed by someone else. I was asked to implement a new design. Now suddenly I get an error when I try to log in. I get a broken page, which I'm not supposed to see, as it is should simply redirect me to my the user's profile page. Instead, this happens:

```
[31/Jan/2018 13:28:47] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2829
[31/Jan/2018 13:28:48] "GET /static/core/bundles/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1787
[31/Jan/2018 13:28:48] "GET /static/core/img/sugar-notagline-23may.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1826
[31/Jan/2018 13:28:48] "GET /static/core/img/tools.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1778
[31/Jan/2018 13:28:48] "GET /static/core/img/library.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1784
[31/Jan/2018 13:28:48] "GET /static/core/img/filter1.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1784
[31/Jan/2018 13:28:48] "GET /static/core/img/settings.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1787
```

There is the main.css file here:

```
./sugarlab/core/static/core/bundles/css/main.css
```

I don't get why that is a 404, since on other pages it seems to be included fine.

The images don't exist, but that shouldn't matter, because this page is not supposed to be shown to the user.

Assuming I've broken some redirect mechanism, what should I be looking for? How would this redirect normally be handled?

Comment: We can guess that `/accounts/login/` is a login page, but we don't know any more that that because you haven't shown us the URL or view. The 200 `POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200` means that the view returns a `200 OK` response. This means that the username and password were probably incorrect. If the password was correct, then you'd expect to see `302` redirect to the next page. As for the 404 errors, you haven't shown any of your [static file settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/) or said whether this is in development or production.

Answer (score 0):

You say you get a 404 error.

This is because your file is not placed where it should.

You said your css file lays `./sugarlab/core/static/core/bundles/css/main.css`.

But the `GET` request shows: `[31/Jan/2018 13:28:48] "GET /static/core/bundles/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1787`

As you can see the `/css` part is missing in the `GET` request. You should correct the path to your CSS.